# Squared reverse triangle inequality

Tags: inequality, normed-spaces

Is there a possibility to obtain a bound on the difference of squared norm $\left\lvert\Vert x \Vert^2 - \Vert y \Vert^2\right\rvert$ in terms of the norm of the difference $\Vert x - y \Vert$?

I have tried to adapt the usual proof of the reverse triangle inequality as follows.

$$
    \Vert x \Vert^2 = \Vert x - y + y \Vert^2 \le (\Vert x - y \Vert + \Vert y \Vert)^2 = \Vert x - y \Vert^2 + 2 \Vert x - y \Vert \, \Vert y \Vert + \Vert y \Vert^2 \\
    \iff \Vert x \Vert^2 - \Vert y \Vert^2 \le \Vert x - y \Vert^2 + 2 \Vert x - y \Vert \, \Vert y \Vert
$$
$$
    \Vert y \Vert^2 = \Vert y - x + x \Vert^2 \le (\Vert y - x \Vert + \Vert x \Vert)^2 = \Vert x - y \Vert^2 + 2 \Vert x - y \Vert \, \Vert x \Vert + \Vert x \Vert^2 \\
    \iff \Vert x \Vert^2 - \Vert y \Vert^2 \ge -\Vert x - y \Vert^2 - 2 \Vert x - y \Vert \, \Vert x \Vert
$$
At this point, I do not know how to convert the bounds including $\Vert x \Vert$, $\Vert y \Vert$ into anything useful.

Comment: $| \| x \|^2 - \|y \|^2 | = | \| x \| - \|y \| || \| x \| + \|y \| |$. Hence there is no global Lipschitz constant, but there is on any bounded set.

Comment: You could say that $(\|x\|-\|y\|)\cdot\|x+y\|\leq|\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2|\leq\|x-y\|\cdot(\|x\|+\|y\|)$

Answer (score 1):

In $\Bbb R$, consider $x=y+1$ with $y>0$. Then $\|x-y\|=1$, but $\bigl|\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2\bigr|=2y+1$ can be arbitrarily large.

However, we do have
$$\|x\|^2-\|y\|^2=(\|x\|-\|y\|)(\|x\|+\|y\|)$$
if that helps you.

Comment: This example helped me understand that it is not actually $\left\lvert\Vert x \Vert^2 - \Vert y \Vert^2 \right\rvert$ that I care about, bur rather the relative size wrt. $\Vert x\Vert$, $\Vert y \Vert$.